# Cannot see last item in ListBox after scrolling to the bottom.

Tags: vb.net

I tried the following code:

```
Dim visibleItems As Int16 = ListBoxLibraryAirplanes.ClientSize.Height / ListBoxLibraryAirplanes.ItemHeight

ListBoxLibraryAirplanes.TopIndex = Math.Max(ListBoxLibraryAirplanes.Items.Count - visibleItems + 1, 0)
```

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Comment: I'm assuming the code snippet is supposed to display the bottom items on the list. It does that for me just fine. I populated `ListBoxAirplanes` with "1" to "20" and placed your code in a button click event. Regardless of the settings of `IntegralHeight` and the size of the listbox, the bottom items always showed up.

Comment: Patrick - Thank you for your effort.  I'm officially stumped.  Manually or from code, I scroll the bar to the bottom and do not see the bottom 1 or 2 entries. - Duardo

Comment: What does `do not see the bottom 1 or 2 entries` mean?  The slots are empty or they are not there?  That code wont even compile using `Option Strict On`.

Comment: @Plutonix, I tried it both ways, with `Option Strict Off` and using `CShort` with `Option Strict On`. Same result, it works fine.

Comment: The listbox is populated from code. When I manually use the scrollbar to scroll to the bottom of the control, I cannot see the last 1 or 2 items (I know they're in the list). It's like the scrollbar does not go down far enough.  This is kind of hard to describe!

Comment: `The listbox is populated from code.` show that

Comment: Just use this `ListBoxLibraryAirplanes.TopIndex = ListBoxLibraryAirplanes.Items.Count - 1`

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. Can I send an image in a question?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up appending a null item to the listbox.  Everything seems to work now. Thanks to Patrick and @Plutonix for your responses.